# Vuetify datatable column filtering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, v-data-table

Has anyone managed to implement individual column filtering into Vuetify datatable? e.g. a dynamic dropdown at the top of each column which is populated with the columns' unique values and filters the table on change.

Comment: That's a generic question. If you want to have more chances for answer, add code and explain your issue :)

Comment: If you have not already done so, you can take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can [edit] your question to provide specific information, such as a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Is the table data connected to a backend?

- Yes? then just send the API call on submit
- No?:
  I assume that you use a similar setup as the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#custom-filter).
  Then you might want to implement a [v-dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/) where you use [v-text-field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/) to be able to edit each field. for that you could simply create a second JSON, where the edited elements are stored in. On submit, could assign the edited data table to the new data table.

`methods: {  submit() { this.yourDataTableJSON = this.editedDataTableJSON }, }`